# I cannot fill out field using urllib, urllib2, mechanize libraries, I want to submit a form

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, mechanize, urllib, python-3.5

Here is a sample of my code with urllib and urllib2:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://example.com/schedule-appointment.php'
name =  "Name:"
phone = "Phone:"
email = "E-mail:"
office = "Office:"
rq_date = "Requested date and time:"
alt_date = "Alternative date and time:"
comments = "Reason for visit:"

values = {
         name : "Vasya",
         phone : "1234567890",
         email : "test@test.com",
         office : "Madison Ave (NYC)",
         rq_date : "01/29/2017 10:00 am" ,
         alt_date : "01/29/2017 10:00 am",
         comments : "this is a test"
       }
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
the_page = response.read()
print(the_page)
```

*and got that message :{"status":false,"msg":"Please fill out all the fields."}*

and another example with mechanize:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser() 
urlofmypage = 'http://www.example.com/schedule-appointment.php'
br.open(urlofmypage) 
print(br.geturl())
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['Name:'] = ['Vasya']   
br['Phone:'] = ['1234567890']
br['E-Mail:'] = ['test@test.com']
br['Office:'] = ['Madison Ave (NYC)']
br['Requested date and time:'] = ['01/29/2017 10:00 am']
br['Alternative date and time:'] = ['01/29/2017 10:00 am']
br['Reason for visit:'] = ['this is a test']

result = br.submit()
print(result)
```

*got that:
    http://www.example.com/schedule-appointment.php*

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Users/vasyaiv/Desktop/Automation test Python/draft.py", line 68, in 
>           br.select_form(nr=0)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py",
>   line 524, in select_form
>           raise FormNotFoundError("no form matching "+description)
>       FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 0

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the relevant PHP files as indicated by these errors: `{"status":false,"msg":"Please fill out all the fields."}` - what fields? `FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 0` - which form? Also, if `blabla.com` is just a placeholder, please use `example.com` as my work proxy doesn't like `blabla.com`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no forms on the page, you try to open with br.open(...).
Check if you target page contains forms in the html code.

more bugs:

1. You are using wrong ids of controls("Name:", "Phone:"). I suspect, that ids of controls on target page looks like "name", "phone" etc.
2. You try to fill text inputs with a lists:
   Right: 
   `br['name'] = 'Vasya'
   br['Phone:'] = '1234567890'`
   etc